# Procedure numbering in algorithm2e

Tags: numbering, algorithms, algorithm2e

When I use the package `algorithm2e`, I find the algorithms can be easily numbered, but the procedure cannot. How can I number the Procedures in `algorithm2e`, like Procedure 1, Procedure 2, ...

> %% Procedure 1
>
> \begin{procedure}
>
> ...
>
> \end{procedure}
>
> %% Procedure 2
>
> \begin{procedure}
>
> ...
>
> \end{procedure}

Comment: When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `procedure` environment is a special form of the `algorithm` environment. Passing the option `procnumbered` to [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) numbers procedures using the same counter as algorithms:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[procnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{procedure}
  \caption{myproc()}
  This is a procedure
\end{procedure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{My algorithm}
  This is a procedure
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of using two different counters for algorithms and procedures, say, Algorithm 1, Procedure 1, Algorithm 2, Procedure 2, Procedure 3, Algorithm 3, ...